# Perl, how to lowercase all hash values?

Tags: perl, hash, lowercase

I need to copy a (one-level) hash to a new one, with all values lowercased.

Do you know a smart method (just to avoid an ugly *foreach*... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spirit of fun, here's a solution using the somewhat obscure `each` function. (Don't believe I have ever used it before.)

```
$new{$key} = lc $val while ($key,$val) = each %old;
```

Comment: I accepted this solution since I can use it with a hash reference, too (which is my effective situation).

Answer (score 13):

```
my %new = map { $_ => lc $old{$_} } keys %old;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a one liner using `map`:

```
my %newHash = map { $_ => lc $existingHash{$_} } keys %existingHash;
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, a different angle to look at the same thing:

```
my %new_hash;
@new_hash{keys %old_hash} = map lc, values %old_hash;
```

And yes, the `keys` and `values` functions are [guaranteed](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) to produce their lists in corresponding order, provided you don't modify the hash they're working on between calling one and the other.

Answer (score 3):

Just another way (that's not as cool now that I know you want a copy of the hash).

```
my %new = %old;
$_ = lc for values %new;
```

Comment: Very illustrative but he *did* ask for a copy, so you should probably point out that yours doesn't. :)

Comment: @hobbs, I missed that, but it's pretty safe the OP knows how to copy a hash. Fixed.